# Assigning int number to an array

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I would like to assign int to an array. What I have is;

```
label = ['rest', 'rest', 'ball', 'cat', 'rest']
```

And I want to get is somethin like this, the int order is not important;

```
labeled = [1, 1, 2, 3, 1]
```

How I did was, I find the np.unique(label) and make dict:

```
labelDict = dict(zip(label, np.arange(1,4))
```

But, I'm stuck at the next step which is to assign this integer to that array label.

Comment: What output do you expect from the data in your example ?

Comment: I recommend scikit-learns [DictVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer.html)

Comment: Use the argument `return_inverse=True` in the call to `np.unique` to get something like your `labeled` sequence.  It won't be exactly the same (i.e. it uses zero-based indexing, and the labels are assigned in sorted order), but it might be close enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a mapping dictionary, similar to what you are doing already:

```
mapping = {i:idx for idx, i in enumerate(set(label))}
```

Then, use the mapping to remap the labels:

```
output = [mapping[i] for i in label]
```

There's no need for numpy, the task can be easily accomplished with base Pyhton.

Comment: Thank you, it works like charms. 

I update this 

output = [mapping[i] +1 for i in label] 

to start with index 1.

Comment: You can update the mapping: `enumerate(set(label), 1)` instead, in case the mapping is re-used later in the script.